# How to perform an inner join on an arbitrary entity using TypeORM?

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I'm building a Node JS BFF app using NestJS. The data layer is a PostgreSQL database with schemas. Another Python backend is in charge of the database schemas, so we just use TypeORM to connect to the database and perform queries.

It works fine for simple queries, but I've been trying to add a join like so:

```js
   const query = this.dataSource
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .from('entities.entities', 'entity')
      .select(['entity.id AS id'])
      .innerJoin('entities.entity_types', 'entity_type', 'entity.entity_type_id = entity_type.id')
      .limit(1)
      .addSelect(['entity_type.name as entity_type_name']);
```

And I get the following error:

```
TypeORMError: "entities" alias was not found. Maybe you forgot to join it?
```

This is due to the fact that I need to specify the entities schema on the entity_types table, and TypeORM is splitting the string to look for aliases instead of understanding it's a full schema+table name. It works on the `from` but not on `innerJoin`.

I've tried specifying the schema in my `new DataSource` statement to get rid of the `entities.` before the table names but TypeORM doesn't seem to respect that and I get a table not found error.

Do you know a way to achieve this? Otherwise, I'm thinking of switching to another package just to do the query building.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find a solution, and because I'm on a deadline, I did switch to another package for the query building: [Kysely](https://github.com/kysely-org/kysely). I generated my types using the generator package and then I created a new instance with the included DummyDriver.